# Attempting to salvage wordpress site

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

Recently, the wordpress site I had hosted on iPower became corrupt & crucial parts of the site's database were lost.

Specifically, the 'options' table in my database (in my case 'wp_hlrv_options') had the majority of it's data irretrievably lost.

The other tables in my database are unscathced, so I'm left wondering what my prospects for recovering the smoldering ashes of my site are. Am I better off rebuilding everything, copying the relevant info from the database (text, CSS settings, etc.) where applicable, or is there a feasible way to replace/repair my corrupted 'wp_hlrv_options' file and get the site working again?

Comment: try this, backup your database, reinstall wordpress (with same table prefix), goto phpmyadmin, select your new database, drop all tables except,  `wp_hlrv_options` then from your backup, move all tables (except `wp_hlrv_options` ) into new database. i am not sure if it works completely, but give it a try, if you do not get any other solution

Comment: Thanks for the advice!